# Передача данных в activity из диалогового окна с пользовательским макетом

Tags: android, xamarin

Здравствуйте. **Xamarin.Android**. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку. Появляется диалоговое окно. Вводит текст. После нажатия на кнопку ОК в диалоговом окне, текстовое поле в главном окне должно быть заполонено введенным текстом. Возникает ошибка. Во время выполнения приложения, после ввода текста переменная ***editText1*** пуста, ее значение ***null***. Это видно на скриншоте. Может, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь код.

**Dialog.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
 <EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/editText1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:minWidth="25px"
 android:minHeight="25px"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain">
  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:minWidth="25px"
  android:minHeight="25px"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="2dp"
  android:background="#F5F5F5"
  android:weightSum="100">
   <Button
   android:text="ok"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_weight="100"
   android:layout_margin="2dp"
   android:background="#778899"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:textSize="18sp"
   android:textStyle="bold" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:minWidth="25px"
  android:minHeight="25px"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="#F5F5F5">
   <LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:minWidth="25px"
   android:minHeight="25px"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="2dp"
   android:background="#667788">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
   </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
namespace App1 {
 [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
 public class MainActivity : Activity {
  Button button1 = null;
  TextView textView1 = null;
  private void funAlert(TextView arg) {
   AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   alert.Create();
   alert.SetTitle("ENTER TEXT");
   alert.SetView(Resource.Layout.Dialog);
   alert.SetNeutralButton("Cancel", (sender, e) => {
    alert.Dispose();
   });
   alert.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, e) => {
    EditText editText1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
    arg.Text = editText1.Text;
   });
   alert.Show();
  }
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
   button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
   textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
   button1.Click += (sender, e) => {
    funAlert(textView1);
   };
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Не знаю шарпов, но могу предположить что `FindViewById`вызывается не у диалога, а у `Activity` - а в ней нет `Id.editText1`. Смотрите внимательнее доку к функции

Comment: Наверное правильней передавать ввод текста из диалога в активность или через интент или через каллбэк.

Answer (score 0):

Поиск элемента `FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);` так, как он написан сейчас, ищет этот `editText1` в интерфейсе основного активити, а не диалога.

Метод `alert.Show();` возвращает объект-диалог, построенный этим билдером. Сохраните его.

Затем вам нужно для сохраненного диалога вызвать `GetWindow()`, и у этого объекта вызывать `FindViewById()`. Предполагаю, что будет выглядеть как-то так (не пинайте, я первый раз вижу С# и Xamarin):

```
// где-то в начале
AlertDialog dialog;
EditText editText1;

// при создании диалога
alert.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, e) => {
    // editText1 уже найдена, см. ниже
    arg.Text = editText1.Text;
});

// при открытии диалога
dialog = alert.Show();
editText1 = dialog.GetWindow().FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
```